# Compact / Separable SETS

Tags: general-topology

I am studying topology and I came across these termes: compact spaces, Hausdorff spaces, separable spaces and metrizable spaces. Now I wonder wether it is possible (and makes sense) to apply the meaning of these concepts to subsets $A\subseteq\Omega$ of a topological space ($\Omega,\mathcal T$).

Indeed, for compact spaces there is an analougus concept for sets:

**Definition (Compact Set).** A set $A\subseteq\Omega$ is called a ($\mathcal T$-) compact set iff for every $\mathcal C\subseteq\mathcal T$ with $$A\subseteq\bigcup_{C\in\mathcal C}C$$ there exists a finite $\mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal T$ such that $$A\subseteq\bigcup_{D\in\mathcal D}D.$$
$\triangle$

This Definition is equivalent to the Statement: ($A,\mathcal T_A$) is a compact space, where $\mathcal T_A$ denotes the subspace topology.

If one considers separable spaces however, I could not find an analogous concept for sets. I wonder wether the following can be correct and make sense:

**Definition (Separable Set).** A set $A\subseteq\Omega$ is called a ($\mathcal T$-) separable set if there exists a countable $S\subseteq A$ such that
$$A = \bigcap_{C\in\mathcal C}C,$$
where $\mathcal C = \{T\supseteq S: (\Omega\setminus T)\in\mathcal T\}$ (i.e. the collection of all closed sets in $\mathcal T$ that contain $S$; this is called the closure of $S$).
$\triangle$

This is this Definition equivalent to a similar Statement for separable subsets?

Why all this? Well, I get the idea of defining space properties and consider subsets as subspaces with the corresponding topology. However, I find this often difficult because if one for instance considers a subset which is neither closed nor open, it is suddenly closed and open in the subspace topology. So why does the literature define certain properties for spaces as a whole and not for subsets? I mean one could eventually just consider $\Omega$ itself as a subset of $\Omega$ so the standard definition becomes a special case of the more general definition with regard to subsets. Or are there potential drawbacks which I don't see?

Comment: Your definition of compact is not right - $\mathcal{D}$ should be a subset of $\mathcal{C}$, not $\mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is rather complex and equivalent to the simpler
$A = A \cap \overline S = cl_A S$ where $cl_A S$ is the closure
of S within the subspace A.

I have not seen any usage of "separable" set while "compact set" is common.
I suggest you continue your line of thought to include connected sets and
connected subspaces.